# Doubts regarding the shape of LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I saw many people with the same issue regarding LSTM, so I'd like to make this question introducing a generic example and then introduce my own.

The input shape as expect is composed by (samples, time steps, features). This was the first time that I got stuck once that many examples provide just two inputs as follows:

```
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(TIMESTEPS, FEATURES), activation='relu', return_sequences = True))
```

If I'm right, when omitted the third parameter, you're just not specifying the number of samples.

So, imagine that I have the follow structure as input:

```
import numpy as np    
np.zeros((BATCHES, TIMESTEPS, FEATURES))
```

Putting it in numbers we could have:

> > np.zeros((2, 3, 5))

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

And that's exactly my case. I have a layer 0 with `input_shape=(480, 16)`, and the `model.predict()` is accepting an input with shape (1, 480, 16) filled after be created using `batch = np.zeros((90, 480, 16))`. A single mini-batch with shape (1, 480, 16) input of predicting is equal to `model.predict(batch[[i]])` but I was expecting as return an array 1D with length equal to 480, and instead, I'm receiving this: `[[0. 1. ... 0. 0.]]` which is < 480.

The values of this array don't matter for now, but his shape should predict a value for each time step.

Where's my problem? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
The entire model declaration for my case is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(480, 16), activation='relu', return_sequences = True)))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.1))
return model
```

An input looks like the following declaration:

```
batch = np.zeros((90, 480, 16)) # this is filled after
input_to_predict = batch[[i]] # where i is in the range > 0  and < 90
model.predict(input_to_predict)
```

Comment: what does your model looks like? why would you expect a different shape?

Comment: @NicolasGervais maybe I didn't understand correctly the definition of the shapes. For me, the shape of the format [[v1 v2 ... vn ]]  with n = 480 should be returned in the prediction. I don't have any hint why is returning [[0. 1. 0. 0.]]

Comment: What I'm saying is that it entirely depends on your model, and you haven't showed it.

Comment: Please post your entire model in the question. It's needed in order to help you.

Comment: @NicolasGervais done, I hope that it could be more clear now. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your LSTM layer doesn't correspond to the one you posted first. Also the code you put doesn't correspond to the output you showed. Please make your code minimal, and reproducible.

Comment: I just omit the activation function and the return_sequences.

Comment: Yes, and that changes everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example above returns shape `(1, 480, 16)`. When you set `return_sequences=True`, Keras will return the time steps dimension (your "middle" dimension), so if your input has 480 time steps, it will output 480 time steps. The last dimension will be the number of units in your last layer.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(480, 16), return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')


batch = np.zeros((90, 480, 16))
input_to_predict = batch[[0]]
model.predict(input_to_predict).shape
```

```
array([[[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

```
(1, 480, 16)
```

If you set `return_sequences=False`, it doesn't return the time steps dimension:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(480, 16), return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')


batch = np.zeros((90, 480, 16))
input_to_predict = batch[[0]]
model.predict(input_to_predict).shape
```

```
(1, 16)
```